# Fill every nth row with a certain value then repeat

Tags: excel

I would like the print every nth (in this case 5th) row with a certain value, then the next nth with another value, then so on. I would like to be able to pull the values to print from another table. For example, I have a table:

```
    Table A:
    George Washington
    Alexander Hamilton
    Thomas Jefferson
```

I want to use information from Table A to create TABLE B.

```
    TABLE B 
    George Washington
    George Washington
    George Washington
    George Washington
    George Washington
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Thomas Jefferson
    Thomas Jefferson
    Thomas Jefferson
    Thomas Jefferson
    Thomas Jefferson
    George Washington
    George Washington
    George Washington
    George Washington
    George Washington
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Alexander Hamilton
    Thomas Jefferson 
    Thomas Jefferson 
    Thomas Jefferson 
    Thomas Jefferson 
    Thomas Jefferson 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source data is in column A of Sheet1, this can be done as follows, on Sheet2, starting at A1 and dragged down:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
```

INDEX takes a given range (in this case, all of column A from Sheet1, where you have your names stored), and returns the value shown in a given row number of that range. Taking ROW() [which shows you the row of the cell a formula is in], divided by 5, rounded up, this will repeat 1 five times, then 2 five times, etc. Therefore, the index will repeat 5 times and go through the list in Sheet1.

Comment: This doesn't deal with the repeating cycle - but you can do it like this =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,IF(ROUNDUP(MOD(ROW(),15)/5,0)=0,3,ROUNDUP(MOD(ROW(),15)/5,0)))

Answer (score 0):

If `Table A` begins in cell `A1`, then insert the following formula into cell `C1` (or any other column, but it must be in row 1) and copy down appropriately:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(FLOOR((ROW()-1)/5,1),COUNTA($A:$A)),0)
```

Where 5 is the number of times you want to repeat the name.

Comment: OFFSET will work, but is less ideal than INDEX as OFFSET is volatile, meaning it recalculates whenever any cell recalculates (even if it wouldn't impact the OFFSET calculation); as well, I personally find it more complex than INDEX, if INDEX is usable, as in this case.

Comment: Fair - I'd suggest changing then to `=INDEX($A:$A,MOD(FLOOR((ROW()-1)/5,1),COUNTA($A:$A))+1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA, then try this:

Public Sub DuplicateItems(rInputRange As Range, rOutputStartCell As Range, lDuplicateCount As Long)

```
Dim rCell   As Range
Dim lOffset As Long
Dim i       As Long

For Each rCell In rInputRange
    For i = 1 To lDuplicateCount
        rOutputStartCell.Offset(lOffset, 0) = rCell
        lOffset = lOffset + 1
    Next i
Next rCell
```

End Sub

rInputRange represents table A, 
rOutputStartCell as the cell to start the output
lDuplicateCount as the amount of replications

Answer (score 0):

A simple way: create the entire first cycle manually. Then put the formula `=A1` in the next cell (assuming A1 is the first cell). Copy or fill down.

Answer (score 0):

Or quite simply:

```vb
Sub MacroMan()

n = 5 '// number of rows to fill
For Each var In WorksheetFunction.Transpose([A1:A3]) '// Change to range of Table A
    Range("B" & n - 4).Resize(5).Value = CStr(var)
    n = n + 5
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
=INDEX(TableA,INT(MOD(ROW()-FirstRow,LenTableA*Repeats)/Repeats)+1)
```

`FirstRow` is the first row of TableB;
`Repeats` is the number of times each entry is repeated; and
`LenTableA` is the number of entries in TableA

Hope that helps.